# Why can't we explain exceptional case-marking as sentences with a three-place predicate?

Tags: syntax, english, theta-role

In this sentence:

> I consider him a good person.

What is prohibiting us from positing a three-place predicate here?
In such a scenario, consider would discharge **three theta-roles** to agent (I), percept (him) and theme (a good person).

I am fully aware of the current explanation behind exceptional case-marking (ECM), either because of **raising-to-object** or doing away with the "protective" CP layer (so that V can assign case to "him" through TP) - I was just wondering where my line of reasoning was flawed.

Comment: Would this alternative explanation be able to account for sentences with ECM before an infinitive like "I consider him to be a good person"? If so, how?

Comment: Your reasoning isn’t flawed, there are theories which regard such verbs as ternary predicates.